# Why are the referenced array's values not changed?

Tags: perl, pass-by-reference

I'm trying to multiply the each component of an array with a scalar, and to do this, have tried the followings;

1-)

```
@foo = (1, 2, 3, 5, 6);
vectorScalarMultiply(\@foo);
print @foo, "\n";

sub vectorScalarMultiply
{
    my $l_vectorRef = $_[0];
    for (my $var = 0; $var < scalar(@temp); $var++) {
        $l_vectorRef->[$var] = $l_vectorRef->[$var] * 5;
    }
}
```

1's Output;

> 12356

2-)

```
@foo = (1, 2, 3, 5, 6);
vectorScalarMultiply(\@foo);
print @foo, "\n";
sub vectorScalarMultiply
{

    my $l_vectorRef = $_[0];
    map { $l_vectorRef->[$_] * 5 } { $l_vectorRef->[$_] };
}
```

2's Output;

> 123456

3-)

```
@foo = (1, 2, 3, 5, 6);
@temp = @{$l_vectorRef};
vectorScalarMultiply(\@foo);
print @foo, "\n";
$l_vectorRef = map { $temp[$_] * 5; } @temp;
```

3's Output;

> 12356

And I haven't been able to figure out what is the problem, and why are they not working, so my **main** question is that what is the problem with these code ?Secondly, how can we solve it ?

Comment: Add `use strict; use warnings;` and fix the errors they show. In 1) you iterate over a non-existimg `@temp` thus the `for` loop isn't executed.

Comment: what is `@temp?`
tried to remplace `@temp` by `@foo` and got the output 51015202530 in 1)
So it seems your error comes from `@temp` undeclared

Comment: You are editing your question and adding what people say is missing. In general this is not the best idea because it invalidates both the answers given so far and also your first item because it now works.

Comment: I have rolled back your changes to the original version. There is no point in posting fixed code, and it made the output that you said you were getting incorrect (I spent along time poring over your question trying to spot a non-existent error).  It also invalidated comments and solutions from others. All in all, not a good look!

Comment: @Borodin I wasn't fixing code according to the answer, they were the original code that I had. I just copying them from a larger code, so I missed a couple of line of code.

Comment: @onur: Then it's strange that some of the code in your latest version displayed no errors, certainly not the ones you describe.

Comment: @Borodin there might be version difference out setups. I mean while editing the question that was not my intent for the edit, sorry for that. Next time I will keep in mind to check the question twice for any missing line of code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Because you forgot `use strict; use warnings;` so didn't notice that `@temp` is undefined so your loop length is `0`.
2. Because you forgot `use strict; use warnings;` so didn't notice that `map { $l_vectorRef->[$_] * 5 } { $l_vectorRef->[$_] };` expects the `{ $l_vectorRef->[$_] }` to be a list. You also didn't assign the result of the `map` anywhere.
3. Because you forgot `use strict; use warnings;` so didn't notice that you never defined `$l_vectorRef` (but if you did, then the map would *overwrite the reference* and not replace the original array)

Comment: What about the 3rd method ?

Comment: LOL. But in the 3rd case `$l_vectorRef` _is_ defined. Or do I miss something?

Comment: @PerlDuck — It wasn't when I wrote the answer. [The OP moved the goalposts.](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/47692470/3)

Comment: @PerlDuck not until like 30 seconds ago :)

Comment: @Quentin Yeah, I forgot some lines while writing the question, sorry about that, but it was't working with the full version of it.

Comment: @onurcanbektas — What about it? There are three items in the numbered list in this answer.

Comment: No, I mean my 3rd method. What is the problem with that ?

Comment: it give "Use of uninitialized value within @temp in multiplication (*) at test.pl line 33." error after adding the strict and warning.

Comment: @onurcanbektas — The third item in the list in my answer discusses that: "the map would overwrite the reference and not replace the original array"

Comment: @Quentin So, if I understood correctly, map would create a new array which is going to be hold by  $l_vectorRef, right ?

Comment: OK, so that error is because you are getting the values of `@temp` (1, 2, etc) and then using them as indexes: `$temp[1]`, up to `$temp[6]` instead of **just using the values**.

Comment: @onurcanbektas — And yes. It creates a new array.

Comment: So what I'm getting from this is that `use strict; use warnings;` might be a good idea?

Comment: also show correct code to do what they want, please?

Answer (score 7):

The first one doesn't work because your loop condition is `$var < scalar(@temp)`, but there is no `@temp`, so the loop never executes.

The second one doesn't work because `map` doesn't modify anything, and you're not assigning the result of the `map` to anything.

The third one doesn't work because you're modifying the variable `$l_vectorRef` inside the sub, and *not* modifying the array that that variable holds a reference to.

Here is a more idiomatic working version:

```
sub vectorScalarMultiply {
    my ($aref) = @_;
    $_ *= 5 for @$aref;
}
```

Comment: As far as I see, $l_vectorRef holds a reference to @foo, so I should be able to modify the values of foo.